# JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode not nesting attributes correctly in output xml

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I have the following JSON string that I'm trying to convert to XML using JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode.

```
    {"Header":
              {"SettingHeaders":
                                [
                                 {"SettingHeaderColumn":{"id":"20","caption":"column1","css":"blue","sortDirection":"2","grouping":"-1"}},
                                 {"SettingHeaderColumn":{"id":"25","caption":"column2","css":"red","sortDirection":"1","grouping":"-1"}}                                    
                                ]  
              }
    }
```

Currently, the XML ouput looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Header>
<SettingHeaders>
  <SettingHeaderColumn>
    <id>20</id>
    <caption>column1</caption>
    <css>blue</css>
    <sortDirection>2</sortDirection>
    <grouping>-1</grouping>
 </SettingHeaderColumn>
</SettingHeaders>
<SettingHeaders>
  <SettingHeaderColumn>
    <id>25</id>
    <caption>column2</caption>
    <css>red</css>
    <sortDirection>1</sortDirection>
    <grouping>-1</grouping>
  </SettingHeaderColumn>
</SettingHeaders>
</Header>
```

but I want it to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Header>
<SettingHeaders>
  <SettingHeaderColumn>
    <id>20</id>
    <caption>column1</caption>
    <css>blue</css>
    <sortDirection>2</sortDirection>
    <grouping>-1</grouping>
  </SettingHeaderColumn>
  <SettingHeaderColumn>
    <id>25</id>
    <caption>column2</caption>
    <css>red</css>
    <sortDirection>1</sortDirection>
    <grouping>-1</grouping>
  </SettingHeaderColumn>
</SettingHeaders>
</Header>
```

(the difference being SettingHeaders should surround a list of SettingHeaderColumns, not encapsulate each one). Is my JSON malformed relative to what I want the XML to look like? Is the method doing something unexpected when it deserializes?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I think this is as designed. At the same time I don't think what you're asking for is unreasonable.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker could you paste link to (or somehow otherwise indicate) the place in documentation you are looking at?

Comment: Sure, I was looking here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm. Take a look at the example towards the bottom. The key for the array property (`person`) is repeated for each element in the array, which is the same behavior you're seeing

Comment: Do you know of another way to convert JSON to XML in this more sensible way?

Comment: Never mind I found a workaround (reformatting my JSON a little)! Thanks so much

Comment: It would be great if you could post how you figured it out as an answer and accept it. That will help future visitors with the same problem